# Sending a login request in Python

Tags: python

So I have this code:

```
import requests

loginData = {
    'sisername': 'cool username',
    'sipassword': 'cool password'
}

with requests.session() as s:
    s.post('http://www.ixl.com/signin', data=loginData)
    response = s.get('http://www.ixl.com')
    print(response.text)
```

I'm trying to send a login to the IXL server, and afterwards keep the login information so that I can answer problems, which is for another time. I still need to know how to send the login information. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're submitting to the wrong page, and with wrong parameters. If you check the form on that page you'll see that the actual submission goes to `https://eu.ixl.com/signin/ajax/page`, so try with:

```
loginData = {
    'username': 'cool username',
    'password': 'cool password',
}

with requests.session() as s:
    res = s.post('https://eu.ixl.com/signin/ajax/page', data=loginData)
    print(res.text)
```

Now, what you want to do after you log-in is a whole other story. You'll probably have to parse `res.text` to see what you got back. As far as I can see, it responds in a JSON format so you can easily check the response:

```
loginData = {
    'username': 'cool username',
    'password': 'cool password',
}

with requests.session() as s:
    res = s.post('https://eu.ixl.com/signin/ajax/page', data=loginData)
    data = res.json()
    if data.get("signinPageError", "false") == "true":
        print("Login failed: {}".format(data.get("errorMessage", "Unknown error")))
    else:
        print("Login successful? I don't know, I don't have valid credentials to check...")
```

What you'll do from there on is up to you...

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this when I get home.

Comment: I tried this, and it didn't seem to work. Every time I received the same error. If you are interested in further helping me, please contact aarongzolla@gmail.com. Thank you :)

Comment: Detecting if login failed will definitely work, what happens when you provide it valid credentials is on you to find out. That's as far as we at SO can help you, and I'm not interested in providing private unpaid (or paid for that matter) work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```py
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("https://ixl.com")

loginData = {
    "qlusername": "admin",
    "qlpassword": "12345"
}

with requests.session() as s:
    res = s.post("https://eu.ixl.com/signin/ajax/page", data=loginData)
    print(res.text)
```